# Beginner in python and tkinter - trying to update values in two classes

Tags: python-3.x, class, tkinter

How do I get the buttons in mainFrame and walletFrame to update across classes?
I basically want to be able to send the balance from walletFrame to mainFrame. See:- vendFunc and walletFunc

Pardon the messiness. It's late and i'm at wits end. Thank you.

```
import tkinter as tk; import random; from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import * ; from tkinter import messagebox
import copy
"""Text here"""
#====================================================================================>
Colour= ['#a6a6a6','#545454','#ff5757','#5ce1e6','#ffde59','#7ed957','#ff914d','#c9e265']
"""0 light gray | 1 dark gray | 2 red | 3 blue | 4 yellow | 5 green | 6 orange - empty | 7 green"""
#====================================================================================>
class globalMain():

    global walBalance
    walBalance = round(random.uniform(2.00, 5.00), 00)

    global vendBalance
    vendBalance = 0.00

    global candyBars
    candyBars = []
    for i in range(6):
        candyBars.append(random.randint(1, 5))

    global coinValues
    coinValues = [5,10,20,50,100,200]

    def __init__ (self, walBalance, candyBars, vendBalance):
        self.walBalance = walBalance
        self.candyBars = candyBars
        self.vendBalance = vendBalance

#====================================================================================>
class mainFrame(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        self.vendMain = None
        self.master = master
        super().__init__(master, bg=Colour[0])
        self.init_mainFrame()


    def init_mainFrame(self):
        self.master.title('Marvelous Mini Munchie Machine')
        self.master.geometry('310x500+500+250')
        #self.master.resizable(False, False)
        self.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, side=LEFT)

        self.vendMain = tk.Frame(self.master, bg='white')
        self.vendMain.pack(fill=tk.BOTH , expand=True, side=LEFT)

        self.topDispF = tk.Canvas(self.vendMain, bg='white', height=100)
        self.topDispF.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, side=TOP, padx=(5), pady=(30,0))

        ct1 = ''; ct2 = ''; ct3 = ''; ct4 = ''; ct5 = ''; ct6 = ''
        var = None if candyBars[0] == 1 else (ct1 := Colour[candyBars[0]])
        var = None if candyBars[1] == 1 else (ct2 := Colour[candyBars[1]])
        var = None if candyBars[2] == 1 else (ct3 := Colour[candyBars[2]])
        var = None if candyBars[3] == 1 else (ct4 := Colour[candyBars[3]])
        var = None if candyBars[4] == 1 else (ct5 := Colour[candyBars[4]])
        var = None if candyBars[5] == 1 else (ct6 := Colour[candyBars[5]])



        def vendFunc():
            global vendBalance
            global walBalance
            vendBalance = walBalance
            self.midBtn_b1.configure(text=(f'Balance: £{vendBalance:.2f}'))
            self.midBtn_bl.configure(text=(f'xxx'))


        self.topDisp_c1 = self.topDispF.create_rectangle(10, 10, 66, 100, outline='', fill=ct1, width=3)
        self.topDisp_c2 = self.topDispF.create_rectangle(110, 10, 170, 100, outline='', fill=ct2, width=3)
        self.topDisp_c3 = self.topDispF.create_rectangle(220, 10, 280, 100, outline='', fill=ct3, width=3)

        self.topBtnF = tk.Canvas(self.vendMain, bg='white', height=20)
        self.topBtnF.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, side=TOP, padx=(5), pady=(10))

        #TODO: add button binding and command here
        self.topBtn_b1 = self.topBtnF.create_rectangle(10, 2, 66, 100, outline='', fill=Colour[0], width=3)
        self.topBtn_b2 = self.topBtnF.create_rectangle(110, 2, 170, 100, outline='', fill=Colour[0], width=3)
        self.topBtn_b3 = self.topBtnF.create_rectangle(220, 2, 280, 100, outline='', fill=Colour[0], width=3)

        self.midBtnF = tk.Canvas(self.vendMain, bg='white', height=20)
        self.midBtnF.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, side=TOP, padx=5, pady=(10))

        if vendBalance == 0:
            self.midBtn_b1 = tk.Button(self.midBtnF, text=(f'INSERT COINS'), command=vendFunc)
            self.midBtn_b1.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=True)
        else:
            self.midBtn_b1 = tk.Button(self.midBtnF, text=(f'Balance: £{vendBalance:.2f}'), command= vendFunc)
            self.midBtn_b1.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=True)

        self.midBtn_bl = tk.Button(self.midBtnF, text='confirm')
        self.midBtn_bl.pack(side=LEFT,fill=BOTH, expand=True)

        self.midBtn_br = tk.Button(self.midBtnF, text='cancel')
        self.midBtn_br.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=BOTH, expand=True)


        self.botDispF = tk.Canvas(self.vendMain, bg='white', height=100)
        self.botDispF.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, side=TOP, padx=(5), pady=(30,0))

        self.botDisp_c1 = self.botDispF.create_rectangle(10, 10, 66, 100, outline='', fill=ct4, width=3)
        self.botDisp_c2 = self.botDispF.create_rectangle(110, 10, 170, 100, outline='', fill=ct5, width=3)
        self.botDisp_c3 = self.botDispF.create_rectangle(220, 10, 280, 100, outline='', fill=ct6, width=3)

        self.botBtnF = tk.Canvas(self.vendMain, bg='white', height=20)
        self.botBtnF.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, side=TOP, padx=(5), pady=(10))

        self.botBtn_b1 = self.botBtnF.create_rectangle(10, 2, 66, 100, outline='', fill=Colour[0], width=3)
        self.botBtn_b2 = self.botBtnF.create_rectangle(110, 2, 170, 100, outline='', fill=Colour[0], width=3)
        self.botBtn_b3 = self.botBtnF.create_rectangle(220, 2, 280, 100, outline='', fill=Colour[0], width=3)

        self.botDispenserF = tk.Canvas(self.vendMain, bg='white', height=50)
        self.botDispenserF.pack( side=BOTTOM, padx=(5), pady=(10))
        self.botDispenserC = self.botDispenserF.create_rectangle(110, 2, 170, 100, outline='', fill=Colour[0], width=3)




#====================================================================================>

class walletFrame(tk.Frame): #Wallet window

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        self.master = master
        super().__init__(master, bg=Colour[1])
        self.init_walletFrame()

    def init_walletFrame(self): #initialisor
        self.master.title('wallet')
        self.master.geometry('560x180+1000+450')
        #self.master.resizable(True, True)
        self.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        self.coinFrame = tk.Canvas(self.master, bg='white', width=560, height=130)
        self.coinFrame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
        self.draw_coins()
        self.wF_walBal()

    def walletFunc(self, coinVal):
        self.coinVal = coinVal
        global vendBalance
        global walBalance
        vendBalance = coinVal
        walBalance = walBalance + coinVal
        self.wF_walBal.configure(text=(f'Wallet Balance is: £{walBalance:.2f} \n Insert into machine.'))

    def wF_walBal(self):
        self.wF_walBal = tk.Button(self.master, bg=Colour[0], text=(f'Wallet Balance is: £{walBalance:.2f} \n Insert into machine.'), width=5, height=5,)
        self.wF_walBal.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=True)

# _________________________________________________________________________________.

    def draw_coins(self):
        #two pound coin
        self.twop = self.coinFrame.create_oval(13,20,110,115,
                                       outline='#edc978', fill='silver', width=18)
        #one pound coin
        self.onep = self.coinFrame.create_oval(135,30,205,110,
                                       outline='#edc978', fill='silver', width=15)
        #fifty pence coin
        self.fiftypc = self.coinFrame.create_oval(222,20.6,302,113,
                                          outline=Colour[1], fill='silver', width=5)
        #twenty pence coin
        self.twentypc = self.coinFrame.create_oval(316,29.5,386,110,
                                           outline='silver', fill=Colour[1], width=8)
        # ten pence coin
        self.tenpc = self.coinFrame.create_oval(400,25,480,120,
                                        outline=Colour[1], fill='silver', width=3)
        # five pence coin
        self.fivepc = self.coinFrame.create_oval(495,35,550,103,
                                         outline='silver', fill=Colour[1], width=3)
# _________________________________________________________________________________.

        self.coinFrame.tag_bind(self.twop, '<Button-1>',
                                self.twopFunc)
        self.coinFrame.tag_bind(self.onep, '<Button-1>',
                                self.onepFunc)
        self.coinFrame.tag_bind(self.fiftypc, '<Button-1>',
                                self.fiftypcFunc)
        self.coinFrame.tag_bind(self.twentypc, '<Button-1>',
                                self.twentypcFunc)
        self.coinFrame.tag_bind(self.tenpc, '<Button-1>',
                                self.tenpcFunc)
        self.coinFrame.tag_bind(self.fivepc, '<Button-1>',
                                self.fivepcFunc)
# _________________________________________________________________________________.

    def twopFunc(self,event):
        self.walletFunc(2.00)

    def onepFunc(self,event):
        self.walletFunc(1.00)

    def fiftypcFunc(self,event):
        self.walletFunc(0.50)

    def twentypcFunc(self,event):
        self.walletFunc(0.20)

    def tenpcFunc(self,event):
        self.walletFunc(0.10)

    def fivepcFunc(self,event):
        self.walletFunc(0.05)

#what need to do - some how init mainFrame class so I can use .configure




    # def walletFunc(self, coinVal):
    #     self.coinVal = coinVal
    #     global vendBalance
    #     global walBalance
    #     vendBalance = coinVal
    #     #self.test.rightFrame.rf_topDips.configure(text='Hi')
    #     self.wF_walBal.configure(text=(f'Wallet Balance: {walBalance:.2f}'))


#todo:Coin Frame - Separator

    print(f'Vending balance = {vendBalance}')
    print(f'Wallet balance = {walBalance}')
    print(f'Candy Bar array = {candyBars}')
    print(f'coin Values = {coinValues}')
#====================================================================================>
if __name__ == '__main__':
    mainFrame_root = tk.Tk()
    walletFrame_root =Toplevel()
    app = mainFrame(mainFrame_root)
    app = walletFrame(walletFrame_root)
    mainFrame_root.mainloop()
```

I tried to figure out a way to initialise it to call it.. but that obviously didn't work.

Comment: How are you running this script? It looks like the mainFrame class and the walletFrame class have two different instances of tk.Tk() as their master. Why do you need the globalMain class?

Comment: Update your code, so people can just copy and run it for testing.

Comment: Updated with eveything in it. Warts and all.

Comment: You need to show how you have tried on what you want to do (*"send the balance from walletFrame to mainFrame"*) and state the problem you came across. Also better use different variables for the instances of `mainFrame` and `walletFrame`, now you have used same variable `app`.

Comment: What if you create an instance of the walletFrame class in the mainFrame class? This will allow you to access the data and methods of the walletFrame instance.